# ggplot - Order x-axis based on a subset factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a big dataset of which I made a smaller test set to play around with but I can't get it working.
I want to order my x.axis based on ascending order of the "late" datapoints, but as you can see the data gets ordered based on the average of both points for one sample.

This is my test data set and the outcome I got so far:

```
Sample  Time    Measurement When
1   20-4-2020   -0.5    early
2   20-4-2020   -0.5    early
3   20-4-2020   -1      early
1   21-4-2020   -0.7    early
2   21-4-2020   -0.6    early
3   21-4-2020   -0.8    early
1   25-4-2020   -1.5    late
2   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
3   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
4   25-4-2020   -1.1    late
5   25-4-2020   -0.7    late
6   25-4-2020   -1.4    late
7   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
8   25-4-2020   -0.7    late
```

```
ggplot(Df, aes(x = reorder(Sample, -Measurement), y = Measurement)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = When), size = 2)
```

first trial image
[image: first trial image]

and how I would like to have it ordered:

endgame
[image: endgame]

I hope someone could help me with this, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a vector of levels that is ordered by only the subset.

```r
library(ggplot2)

levels <- df1$Sample[df1$When=='late'][rev(order(df1$Measurement[df1$When=='late']))]
df1$Sample_ord <- factor(df1$Sample, levels = levels)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Sample_ord, y = Measurement)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = When), size = 2)
```

This shows a "problem": How do you want to deal with **ties**, where late measurements are the same, but early measurements are different.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**data** Thanks user Rui Barradas for the sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Sample  Time    Measurement When
1   20-4-2020   -0.5    early
2   20-4-2020   -0.5    early
3   20-4-2020   -1      early
1   21-4-2020   -0.7    early
2   21-4-2020   -0.6    early
3   21-4-2020   -0.8    early
1   25-4-2020   -1.5    late
2   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
3   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
4   25-4-2020   -1.1    late
5   25-4-2020   -0.7    late
6   25-4-2020   -1.4    late
7   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
8   25-4-2020   -0.7    late
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `reorder` argument `FUN = max`, since the `Sample` is order by decreasing `Measurement`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(reorder(Sample, -Measurement, max), Measurement, colour = When)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Sample  Time    Measurement When
1   20-4-2020   -0.5    early
2   20-4-2020   -0.5    early
3   20-4-2020   -1      early
1   21-4-2020   -0.7    early
2   21-4-2020   -0.6    early
3   21-4-2020   -0.8    early
1   25-4-2020   -1.5    late
2   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
3   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
4   25-4-2020   -1.1    late
5   25-4-2020   -0.7    late
6   25-4-2020   -1.4    late
7   25-4-2020   -0.8    late
8   25-4-2020   -0.7    late
", header = TRUE)

df1$Time <- as.Date(df1$Time, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is not just a conincidence that it works here in this sample ?

Comment: @Tjebo I don't know why it should but to be sure only with another example data set.

Comment: because the OP wants to sort by late measurement, not by the highest value of both measurements

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rui! Tjebo is right, I'll try his solution next.